# How to calculate data within a query VB

Tags: vb.net

How do I calculate data from a .txt file that's within a query in VB?

```
 Dim query = From line In baseball
                Let data = line.Split(","c)
                Let Team = data(0)
                Let Won = data(1)
                Let Lost = data(2)
                Order By Team, Won, Lost
                Select Team, Won, Lost
    dgvOutput.DataSource = query.ToList
    dgvOutput.CurrentCell = Nothing
```

I tried to add Won (30 games won) and Lost (40 games lost) which resulted in 3040 due to rows adding each other... But I had wanted 30+40 which would had gave 70. Any solutions for this?

Comment: Convert `Won` and `Lost` to integers before adding them.

Comment: Like?            Let totalGames = CInt(Won + Lost)       If so it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware of operator overloading behavior. `+` will concatenate strings when the variables are strings and do math when they are numbers. So convert each one individually to a number, then do math.
This is what you want to do, but be aware that if your data is null or cannot be parsed to an integer you will get errors:

```
CInt(Won) + CInt(Lost)
```